# Microsoft.Bot.Connector error : service provider instance was not register

Tags: botframework, asp.net-core-webapi

I followed the sample codes on [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AspNetCore.Echo)

When I send a message to bot, there was an error meesage like this :

**`The service provider instance was not register. Please call RegisterServiceProvider before using ServiceProvider.Instance.`**

which happened on 
`var appCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(this._configuration);`

#### .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore" Version="3.6.0-alpha" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="3.6.0-alpha" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Common" Version="3.6.0-alpha" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

#### Codes

- appsettings.json

  `{ "MicrosoftAppId": "xxxxxxxxx", "MicrosoftAppPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }`
- Startup.cs

  ```
  public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
      Configuration = builder.Build();
  }


  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);

      // Add framework services.
      services.AddMvc(options =>
      {
          options.Filters.Add(typeof(TrustServiceUrlAttribute));
      });


  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
      loggerFactory.AddDebug();


      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseBotAuthentication(new StaticCredentialProvider(
          Configuration.GetSection(MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppIdKey)?.Value,
          Configuration.GetSection(MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppPasswordKey)?.Value));
      app.UseMvc();
  }
  ```
- Webapi - Controller

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("Send")]
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send([FromBody]Activity activity)
  {
          //Error happens on this line!!!
          var appCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(this._configuration);
          var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), appCredentials);

          var reply = activity.CreateReply();

          if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
          {
              // calculate something for us to return
              int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;
              // return our reply to the user
              reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
          }
          else
          {
              //....
          }

          await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
          var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
          return response;
  }
  ```

#### Error (Tested with Emulator)

1. Message

   > The service provider instance was not register. Please call RegisterServiceProvider before using ServiceProvider.Instance.
2. Source

   > Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Common
3. StackTrace

   > at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ServiceProvider.ThrowOnNullInstance()
   >   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.MicrosoftAppCredentials..ctor(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
   >   at LotoBot.Webapi.Controllers.FbMsgController.d__4.MoveNext()

I was stuck for one night, please help me and thank you so much!

Comment: Afrer another half-day try, I found that the codes work with  [Microsoft.Bot.Connector 3.5.1-alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/3.5.1-alpha). Dunno if it was the bug on [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore 3.6.0-alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore/3.6.0-alpha).

Comment: I am very sorry,  this is not a bug of Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore 3.6.0-alpha, anyone who had this problem plz see the [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43445439/7045253) from @Luiz Carlos Faria and [issue #2570](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2570)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `services.UseBotConnector()` on ConfigureServices method of your Startup class.
This method is provided by Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotServiceProviderExtensions extension class.